# How do I create a new database using the MongoDB Node.JS driver?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

How do I programmatically create a database using the MongoDB Node.JS driver?

This looks promising, but I'm not sure how to connect to with the admin credentials and create a new database.

```
var db = new Db('test', new Server('locahost', 27017));
  // Establish connection to db
  db.open(function(err, db) {
    assert.equal(null, err);

    // Add a user to the database
    db.addUser('user3', 'name', function(err, result) {
      assert.equal(null, err);

      // Authenticate
      db.authenticate('user3', 'name', function(err, result) {
        assert.equal(true, result);

        // Logout the db
        db.logout(function(err, result) {
          assert.equal(true, result);

          // Remove the user
          db.removeUser('user3', function(err, result) {
            assert.equal(true, result);

            db.close();
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: Are you saying you tried this and it didn't work, or did you just copy and paste it in here? I'd strongly suggest you at least try something and then post here with specific questions.

Answer (score 6):

in mongodb databases and collections are created on first access.  When the new user first connects and touches their data, their database will get created then.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work.

```
var Db = require('mongodb').Db, 
Server = require('mongodb').Server;

var db = new Db('test', new Server('localhost', 27017));
db.open(function (err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;

  // Use the admin database for the operation
  var adminDb = db.admin();

  adminDb.authenticate('adminLogin', 'adminPwd', function (err, result) {
    db.addUser('userLogin', 'userPwd', function (err, result) {
      console.log(err, result);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you explain what is the difference between 

var db = new Db('test', new Server('localhost', 27017)); 

and 

mongoClient.connect(connString, function(err, db) ....

Answer (score 2):

Try as below:

```
var adminuser = "admin";
var adminpass = "admin";
var server = "localhost";
var port   = 27017; 
var dbName = "mydatabase";
var mongodb          = require('mongodb');
var mongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

var connString = "mongodb://"+adminuser+":"+adminpass+"@"+server+":"+port+"/"+dbName;
    mongoClient.connect(connString, function(err, db) {
        if(!err) {
            console.log("\nMongo DB connected\n");                
        }
        else{
            console.log("Mongo DB could not be connected");
            process.exit(0);
        }
    });
```